# Sharing data between views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I have a little problem with C# ViewData.

In first view, I am calling:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IndividualModel, "_Individual", 
                     new ViewDataDictionary { { "processType", "ABC" } })
```

And in second i wanna put this value to variable like this:

```
var processType = ViewData["processType"];
```

But, `processType` from dictionary is always null.

Please, do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How do you define processtype and how do you send it from the controller? Try making a null check and assigning var processtype only if ViewData["processType""] isn´t null

Answer (score 0):

Your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) of `EditorFor()` where the 3rd parameter (`additionalViewData`) is typeof `object`, not typeof `ViewDataDictionary`. From the docs (my emphasis)

> additionalViewData
>   Type: **System.Object**
>   An anonymous object that can contain additional view data that will be **merged** into the ViewDataDictionary<TModel> instance that is created for the template.

Change the method to

```cs
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IndividualModel, "_Individual", new { processType = "ABC" })
```

and in the template

```cs
@{ var processType = ViewData["processType"]; }
<div>@processType</div> // renders "ABC"
```